# Azure Powershell - Application Gateway Configuration

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have been given the responsibility for managing an Azure application gateway. The gateway is complex with 16 sites each with different SSL certificates, httplisteners, etc.  The previous admin kept NO documentation. The short question is there a way I can use powershell to query and parse the existing configuration to a new script that I could use to rebuild the gateway if something breaks? I dont want to be messing with json and would prefer using powershell cmdlets, (Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway..., Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway, etc).

Any sample scripts would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To load the whole gateway configuration via Powershell use:

Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name MyAppGw -ResourceGroupName MyAppGwRG

[Source](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-solutions/configuring-azure-application-gateway-with-powershell/)

You can also edit this [XML template file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-probe-classic-ps#configure-an-application-gateway-by-using-xml) to record all the app gateway settings.